# How to properly install mysql connector in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, mysql-connector

First of all I'd like to say that it is a project for a course in my university and at the same time my first app for Android which is more complicated that a calculator, so I understand that I could have done some unforgivable mistakes, but my priority is that the code should work. It can be insecure and not considering some cases, but as long as those cases won't appear, it will do.

My app is intended to be running on Android and first of all there should appear login screen which takes login and password, makes the hash of the password and contacts a database on a web server to compare hashes. I was told to use a free database db4free.net.

I created a class Serwer, which would be responsible exclusively for contacting the database. As far as I understood from tutorials and stackoverflow questions and answers, the connection should consist of:

1. Loading the driver,
2. Registering it in the DriverManager class,
3. Using getConnection method to open the connection, passing the credentials,
4. Preparing and executing SQL query,
5. Fetching a result set.

I also learned that I should download a mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar file. As some threads on stackoverflow suggested, I copied it into main directory of the project (I have to copy the workspace and take to professor's computer when I finish), added it to Libraries tab of properties as an external library. Now when I run the project on my smartphone, I get a *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"* error. I also tried to check the library in Order and Export tab - then it even doesn't compile, returning *Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1*.

I've tried many scenarios in other stackoverflow threads, such as cleaning the project in many configurations, changing the order of build path, etc. I suspect that I've made a simple, stupid mistake that I do not see and I hope you will recognize it.

Here is my Serwer class:

```
package com.planer.serwer;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Driver;

import com.planer.MainActivity;
import com.example.planer.R;
import com.planer.pracownik.Pracownik;

public class Serwer {
        private Connection conn = null;
        private static Driver driver;
        private static int status;
        private MainActivity parentActivity;

        private final String user = parentActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.db_login);
        private final String pass = parentActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.db_pass);
        private final String url= "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/kalendarzplaner";

        public static final int STATUS_GOOD = 0;
        public static final int STATUS_NO_CONNECTION = 1;
        public static final int STATUS_NOT_AUTHENTICATED = 2;
        public static final int STATUS_SQL_EXCEPTION = 4;
        public static final int STATUS_NO_DRIVER = 8;


        public Serwer(MainActivity parentActivity){
            status = STATUS_NO_CONNECTION;
            try {
                driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                status |= STATUS_NO_DRIVER;
            } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
                status |= STATUS_NO_DRIVER;
            }
            this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        }

        public Pracownik authorize(String login, String passhash){
            Pracownik pracownik = new Pracownik("","",false,status);
            status |= this.polacz();
            if(status != Serwer.STATUS_GOOD) {
                pracownik.status |= status;
                return pracownik;
            }
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            String query = "select passhash, imie_nazwisko, czy_kierownik from auth where login='" + login + "';";
            try {
                statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                resultSet.first();
                if(resultSet.getString("passhash").toString().compareTo(passhash)!= 0){
                    status |= Serwer.STATUS_NOT_AUTHENTICATED;
                    pracownik.status |= status;
                    return pracownik;
                }
                pracownik.login = login;
                pracownik.imie_nazwisko = resultSet.getString("imie_nazwisko");
                pracownik.czy_kierownik = resultSet.getBoolean("czy_kierownik");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                pracownik.status |= Pracownik.STATUS_SQL_EXCEPTION;
            }           
            return pracownik;
        }


        public int polacz() {
            int done = STATUS_NO_CONNECTION;
            if((status & STATUS_NO_DRIVER) != 0)
                return done;
            // Connection
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                done = Serwer.STATUS_GOOD;
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
                done |= Serwer.STATUS_SQL_EXCEPTION;
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            } 
            return done;
        }
}
```

As I said, the status of the result of authorise method is 9, which is expected when the driver is not loaded. I also append my workspace contents.

[image: Workspace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to start by suggesting that you tried out Android Studio. It's the new more modern IDE developed specifically for the purpose of Android Development.

Secondly, contacting a database on Android is a lot different than for example contacting a DB from Java/C# in an Desktop application.

To contact an online MySQL Database you need a RESTful service (written in PHP for example) that gets the data from the database and sends it over to the application. The service is like a communication point between the App and the Database. The service usually sends data to the application in a human-unfriendly format like JSON, so your app needs to parse that and then display it.

Comment: Yes, I've already heard that I should use Android Studio, but unfortunatelly the professor is insisting on Eclipse. Thanks for advice and tutorial, but I don't think that the server I'm using can offer writing code in PHP and as before, the server db4free is forced by the professor.

Comment: Using Eclipse is not a problem really. About the database...db4free is okay as well but to connect to android, a RESTful service is the best technique and probably about the only one used today with a few exceptions. No one encourages using a ODBC Driver for Android. In that sense, keep using the DB you were told to, find a free web hosting site like https://www.awardspace.com/ and use it to just host your php services there. They can still communicate with a database not on the same server if you point to the right IP of db4free. Maybe ask your professor if he agrees with your solution.

Comment: Thank you, I talked to the professor and he agreed. Now it works properly.